# SQL data transpose query?

Tags: mysql, pivot

How to convert long data to wide data without hard coding in SQL?

If any one please help me.

Regards
[Manish Bose](https://www.allaboutsql.tech/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean splitting data in chunk?

Comment: Ready-to-use pivotting stored procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136355/10138734

Comment: Another stored proc for pivoting: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot  -- If "pivoting is how what you need, then elaborate.